Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'todooo' available as request attribute
While running the insert without validation it works, but when I added validation like targetdate must be future date and trying to show in form twoway binding, then this error started.
No idea on which direction I need to think of.
Error:
2024-04-26T12:24:20.955-04:00 DEBUG 11520 --- [ToDo] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'insert', model {todo=ToDo{id=5, username='Test1, description='HelloWorld, targetDate=2020-04-26, creationDate=2024-04-26, done=false, attachment= XX}, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.todo=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'todo' on field 'targetDate': rejected value [2020-04-26]; codes [Future.todo.targetDate,Future.targetDate,Future.java.time.LocalDate,Future]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [todo.targetDate,targetDate]; arguments []; default message [targetDate]]; default message [springboot-starter-validation-@size---> ID -->  ALLOWED to enter only FUTURE dates ]}
2024-04-26T12:24:20.962-04:00 DEBUG 11520 --- [ToDo] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/insert.jsp]
2024-04-26T12:24:21.034-04:00 ERROR 11520 --- [ToDo] [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag       : Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'todooo' available as request attribute

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'todooo' available as request attribute

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/jsp/insert.jsp] at line [34]

31: 
32:             <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="todooo">
33:                 <p><label>id : </label>
34:                     <form:input type="text" path="id" required="required"   />
35: 
36:                 <p><label>username : </label>
37:                     <form:input type="text" path="username" required="required"    />


ToDo_Controller.java

    @RequestMapping(value  = "/insert", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get_insert_todo(ModelMap modelMap){
        String u_retrived = (String) modelMap.get("uid");
        Todo todo_obj = new Todo(toDo_services.listAllToDo().size()+1,u_retrived,"HelloWorld",LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plusYears(1),false );

        modelMap.put("todooo", todo_obj);

        return "insert";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value  = "/insert", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post_insert_data(ModelMap modelMap, @Valid Todo todooo, BindingResult bindingResult){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return  "insert";  
        }

        String u_retrived = (String) modelMap.get("uid");
        toDo_services.insert_todo(String.valueOf(todooo.getId()), u_retrived, todooo.getDescription(), todooo.getCreationDate(), todooo.getTargetDate(), todooo.getDone());
        return "redirect:list";
    }



ToDo_Services.java

    public List<Todo> insert_todo(String id,
                                  String username,
                                  String description,
                                  LocalDate creationDate,
                                  LocalDate targetDate,
                                  boolean done) {

        int i1 = id.isEmpty() ? listToDo.size()+1 : Integer.valueOf(id);
        boolean addedorNot = listToDo.add(new Todo(  i1 , username,description,creationDate,targetDate, done));
        l1.info("insertingg(insert_todo).... given data T/F ==" + addedorNot);
        return  listToDo;
    }


insert.jsp

<%@ taglib prefix="test1" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>


<html>
    <head>
        <link href="\webjars\bootstrap\5.1.3\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title> Add : Todo    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">
            

            <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="todooo">
                <p><label>id : </label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="id" required="required"   />

                <p><label>username : </label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="username" required="required"    />

                <p><label>description : </label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="description" required="required"   />

                <p><label>creationDate : </label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="creationDate" required="required"    />
                    
                <p><label>targetDate : </label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="targetDate" required="required"    />
                    <form:errors path="targetDate"   />
                    
                <p><label>done : </label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="done" required="required"    />

                <p><input type="submit" value=" + "  class="btn btn-success"> </input>
            </form:form>

            <p>
                Hint1:
            <p>
                Hint2:
<p><p>

        </div>
        <script src="\webjars\bootstrap\5.1.3\js\bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="\webjars\jquery\3.6.0\jquery.min.js"> </script>
    </body>
    <html>


ToDo.java

package springboot.ToDo.Model;


import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

public class Todo {

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate creationDate;
    @Future(message ="targetDate -->  ALLOWED to enter only FUTURE dates " )
    private LocalDate targetDate;
    private boolean done;



    public LocalDate getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(LocalDate creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Todo(int id, String username, String description, LocalDate creationDate , LocalDate targetDate, boolean done ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.description = description;
        this.creationDate =creationDate;
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
        this.done = done;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public LocalDate getTargetDate() {
        return targetDate;
    }

    public void setTargetDate(LocalDate targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }

    public boolean getDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ToDo{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username +
                ", description='" + description +
                ", targetDate=" + targetDate +
                ", creationDate=" + creationDate +
                ", done=" + done
                '}';
    }
}

Tried to debug the code and the error is triggered only when validation + two way binding are added. Without validation + two way binding tags, everything works fine.

UPDATE:
PROBLEM is solved now by just adding @Valid @ModelAttribute("todooo")
Thanks  to ...

Roman C'

https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-available-as-request-attribute#comment-295414




The error comes to you application because you didn't specify an attribute of the model passed to the POST method. Add @ModelAttribute("todooo") to the method parameter:
public String post_insert_data(ModelMap modelMap, @Valid @ModelAttribute("todooo") Todo todooo, BindingResult bindingResult){
       


Thanks for your expertise.
Unfortunately, I cant vote, I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote

@Sumitツ You can save this question for further references, and when you reach 15 points or higher then return back and vote up this answer. That is more powerful acknolagement you can give.

Sure (Y) I will do it
